# How to enable "Relation view" feature in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, innodb

I am trying to establish Foreign Key relationships between a number of tables but cannot find the "Relation view" option. I have ensured my database and the relevant tables are using InnoDB.

I am using a Mac with MAMP and using PHPMyAdmin to manage my database.

I have tried a number of tutorials but have been unsuccessful including:
[Enabling bookmarks and other advanced features in phpMyAdmin](http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/pma_config.php).

Comment: go to the structure view, and use ctrl+find and type 'relation', hope you find

Comment: Thanks but clearly didn't read, I am using a Mac so it would be 'cmd' and the option it is not displayed on the page.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I edited your question because there were a lot of unnecessary introductions in it. Look at it: it became twice as short, and still it contains the same relevant information. Condensed questions are simpler to answer, so it is in your best interest to describe your problem as compactly as possible, refraining from any premature thanksgiving and speeches about how much of a beginner you are : ) Also note how I formatted the link you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this tutorial, I found this helpful and also includes some configuration files which may be of use  http://www.lynda.com/phpMyAdmin-tutorials/Setting-up-foreign-key-constraint/144202/157544-4.html

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. Good tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved this, it appears there are a number of prerequisites that need to be done when using MAMP on the MAC. Including:

1. Import the phpmyadmin database which is found in Mamp/Bin/PhpMyAdmin/Example/Create_Tables.sql. Go to the import tab and select this file.

   2. Create a pma user account by clicking on the database then click user. Details can be found in the link provided.
   3. Update config.inc.php in phpMyAdmin. Details can be found in the link provided.
   4. Restart your MAMP servers

Link:http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/pma_config.php

Answer (score 0):

It turns out all you need to do is import `create_tables.sql` from phpMyAdmin. `create_tables.sql` is currently found under `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/phpMyAdmin/sql` for mamp pro users. For mamp users it's under `/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/sql`. Note that the file location seems to change form versions to versions.